# File Watcher Script Informatica

Tags: linux, informatica

For our project we are scheduling Informatica Workflows in Schedulers. Can anyone provide any script which will check File and send a mail for file not available without failing the Workflow. I `have` written a one but problem is it is failing the Workflow. And if that happens We have to create again New Scheduler.
Here is my script :

```
PROC_RC=0
FileDir=$1
FileIden=$2
FileName=$3
DataSource=$4
cd $FileDir
ls -l $FileIden* > $FileName
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FileName")
if [ $FILESIZE -eq 0 ]
then
PROC_RC=1
  mail -s "No Source File Available" xyz@ <<< "Hi,

No File Received for $DataSource Today.

Thanks,
Note: This is a system generated mail. Please do not reply."
fi
exit $PROC_RC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command task properties tab you can uncheck the "Fail task if any command fails", It will not fail your workflow.

But in this case you have to do error handling at script level